# Unit Testing with SubSonic, ActiveRecord and SqlQuery

Tags: unit-testing, subsonic, subsonic-active-record

I'm trying to use the built-in testing features of Subsonic 3.0.0.4 by setting my connection string to "Test".  My data access routines use the SqlQuery class.  When I try to run a test against the "in-memory" repository, I receive this error:

> System.ArgumentException: Format of
>   the initialization string does not
>   conform to specification starting at
>   index 0.

When debugging, I can see that the database class, which inherits from IQuerySurface, is in test mode.

Is it possible to use the built-in testing feature in Subsonic with ActiveRecord and SQLQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the built-in testing feature in Subsonic with ActiveRecord and SQLQuery?

No the built-in testing only works with Linq queries